# How to find range of values for which a sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Say you had the sequence $U_{n+1} = 2bU_n$ where $U_1 = 6$.  How would you find the range of values of b for which the sequence converges?

Comment: I will assume you really mean sequence and not the series $\sum_1^\infty U_n$. So $U_1=6$, $U_2=6(2b)$, $U_3=6(2b)^2$, $U_4=6(2b)^3$, and so on. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Definitely a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you have to find out for which values of x a sequence x^n converges.
These are all values, which converge to zero (don't miss the negative ones!) and one more special case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that relates to my sequence.  Like, I know it means I have to find the values that the sequence will be heading to a limiting value.

Comment: As Andre commented above, the value of the sequence is 6 (2b)^n with n->inf, so set x=2b

Comment: I'm trying but this just isn't clicking with me where this is going.  So 2b^n, and I have to find the values of b that make it converge.  I would naturally be thinking fractions here, but that's all I'm really thinking.

Comment: E.g.: What does 1.001^n converge to?

Comment: 2?  Eventually though it would go above 2. Would it be all the values when 2b < 1?

Comment: Indeed it diverges for all values <= -1 and > 1. Now it is trivial to get the range for b.

Comment: Sorry did you mean >= -1 and < 1?

Comment: Thats the range for which x^n CONverges. So for which interval does b in (2b)^n converge?

Comment: >= -0.5 and < 0.5?

Comment: Nearly, indeed the converging range is the complement of the diverging range. The diverging ranges are x <= -1 and x > 1, so b must be in ]-0.5;0.5]

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $U^{n+1} = 2bU^n$, $U^1 = 6$, is a geometric progression with ratio $2b$ and first term $6$. The general term is $U^n = 6(2b)^{n-1}$. The sequence is convergent for ratio $1 < 2b \leq 1$ and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} U^n = 
\begin{cases}
0, \quad |2b|<1,
\\
6, \quad 2b = 1.
\end{cases}
$$